# Conditional Formatting for Null Values

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am having trouble to add a statement for if a value is null in my sharepoint list. Currently this is the code I have that is working:

```
{
     "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
     formatting.schema.json",
     "elmType": "div",
     "txtContent": "@currentField",
     "style": {
              "color": "black",
              "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= @now - 31536000000, 
              '#ff9999',if(@currentField <= @now - 28944000000 && @currentField > @now - 
              31536000000,'#ffff99', 'white'))"
                }
 }
```

Date values are what is being stored in this column, what code do I need to add for ows that have no values to show up with a blue highlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint JSON Formatting, you can check if date & time column is blank like:

```
Number(@currentField) == 0
```

You can find other ways to check if SharePoint date & time column is empty or not at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

---

For your requirements, use this JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "black",
        "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) !=0 ,if(@currentField <= @now - 31536000000,'#ff9999',if(@currentField <= @now - 28944000000 && @currentField > @now - 31536000000,'#ffff99','white')),'#0000ff')"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!